# combining bootstrap breakpoints in class name

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

Do i really have to declare my  bootstrap classes as a combination of all screen sizes and column span for responsiveness?

I am using <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-4 >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
You don't have to declare all the bootstrap classes.
The smaller breakpoint will be applied to all the larger ones unless you add a bigger breakpoint specifically.

Only this will suffice:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
```